# Laravel - Incorrect JSON response structure when using unique

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, collections

So I've got a basic query which returns our `Period` model, this query can optionally filter these periods by `Project` relationships. Here is a stripped back version below...

```
$query = Period::query();

$query->whereIn('project_id', [1, 2]);

$entries = $query->get();

$projects = $entries->pluck('project')->unique();

return response()->json($projects);
```

So given the above code, for some reason the JSON returned isn't an array of objects, it an object of objects, e.g `{"0":{}, "2":{}}`. If I remove the `unique()` call then it correctly returns an an array of objects.

The collection with and without the unique method are both instances of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and both `items` property of the collection are an array of objects so I can't see *why* it's returning a difference structure.

The only difference I can see is that when I `dd` the collection with the `unique` call, then the keys are green, while without the unique call they are blue, indicating a string and integer, but when I do `$projects->keys()` they're all integers (but could `keys` be casting them to integers?).

With the `unique` call:
[image: with unique call]

Without the `unique` call:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out, `unique` keeps the original keys of the item which means they won't necessarily be in in numerical order, and thus can't be JSON encoded so it returns an object instead.

Using `->unique()->values()` fixes the issue.

Comment: Beat me to it :)